# Angular controller syntax

Tags: angularjs, controller

While reviewing angular interview [question and answers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/891718/AngularJS-Interview-Questions-and-Answers), I noticed that the author has written the controller's syntax as follows:

```
function Customer($scope)
{
        $scope.CustomerName = "Shiv";
        $scope.CustomerCode = "1001";
        $scope.Add = function () {
        }
        $scope.Update = function () {
        }
}
```

I'm accustom to writing controllers in this way:

```
app.controller('Customer', function($scope) {
  $scope.CustomerName = "Shiv";
  $scope.CustomerCode = "1001";
  $scope.Add = function () {}
  $scope.Update = function () {}
});
```

How would I use the authors controller syntax in an angular project???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Papa who is the nationally recognized "guru" on Angular and he recommends creating controllers as in your first example.  See [HERE](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

app.controller('Customer',Customer($scope))

Answer (score 0):

The author is simply using a named function, instead of directly passing an anonymous function like you did.

```
app.controller('Customer',Customer);

function Customer($scope) {
  ...
}
```

Also, I'd recommend looking into **dependency injection**, which is an Angular best practice required by its Strict Mode. Like so...

```
app.controller('Customer',Customer);

// Dependencies declared here
// This tells angular what to inject into your controller
Customer.$inject = ['$scope'];

// Controller Constructor Function
// You can now safely use $scope.
function Customer($scope) {
  ...
}
```

> Check out [**Using StrictDI** in Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp). At the bottom there's a JS example for BadController, GoodController1, and GoodController2
>
> The first **GoodController1** would be an improvement to your style. The author went for the **GoodController2** syntax